# I want to Read out the news out loud using feedparser

Tags: python, pi-4, raspbian-buster

I have a RPi 4B running RaspberryPi OS buster and I want to be able to speak out the news using ./speech.
I have been following a [tutorial](https://randomconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-your-raspberry-pi-to-speak-news.html) and I got everything up and running but I am having some error popping up, again and again, tried everything I could but no luck.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_news.py", line 4, in <module>
    import feedparser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feedparser'
```

I thought it might be due to virtual environment not being there, after doing so, I am still facing the same and even more errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_news.py", line 4, in <module>
    import feedparser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .api import parse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser/api.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import http
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser/http.py", line 156
    new_pieces[1] = f'{url_pieces.hostname}:{url_pieces.port}'
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me fix this...my idea is I want the RPi to speak out the news headlines by reading it off BBC India or India Today.

Comment: What command are you using to run your scripts? Try `python3` instead of `python`...

Comment: Tried, No luck.

Comment: Did you accidentally use `pip` instead of `pip3` while installing the modules? And don't use `sudo` with `pip3`.

Comment: And also, please use backticks (`) to format your code. Put 3 backticks (```) before the start and end of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I found the solution.
I had a speech.sh which was an executable script in another folder, so the permission to run it was local to that folder which I wasn't aware of. So I copied it to the local read_news folder and ran **sudo chmod 755 {script name }** and deactivated my venv and ran pip3 install feedparser and that did it for me.